# how to switch columns of a list with rows of another list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list having some numpy arrays. I want to switch rows and columns of this list. My input list is:

```
array=[[np.array([[1.,2.]]), np.array([[5.,6.]]), np.array([[7.,8.]])],\
       [np.array([[10.,20.]]), np.array([[50.,60.]]), np.array([[70.,80.]])],\
       [np.array([[100.,200.]]), np.array([[500.,600.]]), np.array([[700.,800.]])]]
```

My `array` is a list which has three lists. Each list also has three numpy arrays. I want to rearrange these three lists. I want my first list to be the first array of first list, first array of second list and first array of third list. In the second list, I want to have second array of first list, second array of second list and second array of third list. For the third list again I want to have third arrays of first, second and third list. I mean I want to get:

```
[[np.array([[1.,2.]]), np.array([[10.,20.]]), np.array([[100.,200.]])],\
 [np.array([[5.,6.]]), np.array([[50.,60.]]), np.array([[500.,600.]])],\
 [np.array([[7.,8.]]), np.array([[70.,80.]]), np.array([[700.,800.]])]]
```

I tried:

```
switched=[]
for i in range (len(array)-1):
    for j in range (len (array[i])):
        switched.append ([array[i][j], array[i+1][j]])
```

But it does not give me what I want.
I do appreciate if anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You can use zip build-in function of python to switch lines and columns.

```
array_tranformed = [list(column) for column in zip(*array)]
```

Comment: Dear @Vincent Bénet, Thanks for giving tiem to my problem. When I tried your solution, I got different output from what I expected. Can you please check it?

Comment: Hi @Ali_d answer edited (removed one solution and change one other. I have tested on different list than your input. Sorry for that!
This solution is way faster that the green checked solution... ^^ (One complexity degree less)

Answer (score 2):

`switched = [[array[j][i] for j in range(len(array))] for i in range(len(array[0]))]` should do the trick if your lists have the same size.

Comment: Dear @TUI lover, Thanks for your intelligent solution. When I try it, I face en error. Can you please check it? I think some typos or maybe brackets are source of issue.

Comment: Can you send me your error? Cannot reproduce

Comment: this is the error: `SyntaxError: closing parenthesis ']' does not match opening parenthesis '('`. I solved it but the result is defferent from what I expected.

Comment: @Ali_d have you tried with my corrected version? Seems like it works for me